# Error in generating RDLC Reports in Remote server

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rdlc

In my MVC Application I'm using RDLC reports, in local server everything is well, but when app is published on remote server the following error is appeared: "**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies**".

[Error shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwmTQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The version of ReportViewer installed is different of the dll in the MVC application.

Align both to the same version and it will be ok.

Comment: I'm not using ReportViewer to display Report, only I show it on the browser as pdf